# Python Cant remove spaces from returned string

Tags: python, string, winapi

I have tried .replace, I have tried trim I have tried almost every solution out there to get these damn white spaces to leave me alone but they wont go away.

```
import win32api
import string
import re

disks = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
disks = disks.translate({ord(c): None for c in ':\\ '})

disks = re.sub(r'\s+','',disks, flags=re.UNICODE)

print (disks)

for disk in disks.strip().split(): # or just disks without the other stuff
    print('Trying drive: '+disk)
    try:
        drives,_,_,_,_ = win32api.GetVolumeInformation(disk+':\\')
        print ('Got info for drive: ' + disk)
        print(drives)
    except Exception as details:
        print('Ooops, not a hard drive')
```

output without .strip().split()

```
== RESTART: C:\~~~~~~ ==
C D E F 
Trying drive: C
Got info for drive: C
Windows
Trying drive:  
Ooops, not a hard drive
Trying drive: D
Ooops, not a hard drive
Trying drive:  
Ooops, not a hard drive
Trying drive: E
Got info for drive: E
Media 2
Trying drive:  
Ooops, not a hard drive
Trying drive: F
Ooops, not a hard drive
Trying drive:  
Ooops, not a hard drive
```

output without .strip().split()

```
== RESTART: C:\~~~~ ==
C D E F 
Trying drive: C D E F 
Ooops, not a hard drive
```

have now tried

```
" ".join(disks.split())
```

Comment: I think you should stop guessing and read the documentation. There are no spaces in this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the required delimiters in the `split` itself. Something like:

```
import win32api

disks = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
disks = disks.split(":\\\x00")

for disk in disks:
    if len(disk):
        print('Trying drive: '+disk)
        try:
            drives = win32api.GetVolumeInformation(disk+':\\')
            print ('Got info for drive: ' + disk)
            print(drives)
        except Exception as details:
            print('Ooops, not a hard drive')
```

For me this produces something like:

```
Trying drive: C
Got info for drive: C
('OS', -1470383266, 255, 65470719, 'NTFS')
Trying drive: D
Ooops, not a hard drive
Trying drive: G
Ooops, not a hard drive
Trying drive: H
Ooops, not a hard drive
Trying drive: W
Got info for drive: W
('Offline', 0, 255, 6, 'CSC-CACHE')
```

Comment: Your code works but [the delimiter is just "\0"](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32api__GetLogicalDriveStrings_meth.html). Edit: code is correct because you append ":\\" for `GetVolumeInformation()` call.

Comment: That does work for me, except it leaves one space at the end, which is honestly fine now! Thanks a lot!